# Failed to execute goal net.sf.mavenjython:jython-compile-maven-plugin:1.0:jython

Tags: maven-3, robotium, jython-2.5

I'm trying to run a jython script from my Junit testcases. I have included the maven-jython-plugin.jar and jython.jar as well. As well as updated my pom.xml file accordingly. But when I run 'mvn install', I get following error:

`Failed to execute goal net.sf.mavenjython:jython-compile-maven-plugin:1.0:jython (pydevLockUnlock) on project NTLauncherTest: extracting org/python/antlr/op/AugLoad.class from jython artifact jar failed: target/jython-plugins-tmp/org/python/antlr/op/AugLoad.class (Too many open files)`

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong and have a solution for this?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that maven can keep a lot of jar filehandles open. Check out this link for suggestions on how to troubleshoot that.

http://www.thinkplexx.com/learn/howto/maven2/debug/fixing-too-many-open-files-maven-problem-solution-for-teamcity-hudson-local-and-ssh-shell-environments

I've found that just re-running `mvn install` can lead to a successful build.